# filter list with multiple checkboxes in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to filter a `ng-repeat` list of items with multiple catgories checkboxes.

i read this [Filtering by multiple checkboxes in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457809/filtering-by-multiple-checkboxes-in-angularjs) and watched the videos by Egghead, but i have an error on a simple `for` loop and i don't understand:

```
ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

here is a plunker with the code : http://plnkr.co/edit/p538ALfs00JTFQ6mKT9j

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use strict mode (`'use strict';`), you need to declare your variables.  Your `checkboxFilter` uses many variables that are never defined (`i` included).  You can get past the your initial issues by changing script.js:22-23 to:

```
      var i,j,k,filter_cat,filter_value,filter_name,matchingItems = [];
```

You have three other problems after that...

1. Line 37, This code is looking for a property named `filter_cat`: `items[i].filter_cat`, when what you wanted was to look for a property name with the value of `filter_cat`, so this is what you want: `items[i].[filter_cat]`.
2. Your json data has lowercase field names and your code is searching on uppercase (Type vs type)
3. Your json data has lowercase values and your code is searching on uppercase (Fruit vs fruit)

Here is a partial edit that gets you on the right track.  You'll still need to modify your json or compare lowercase (I partially modified your json): http://plnkr.co/edit/d7p4QthXJg4ao34ATWla?p=preview

Comment: thank you ! i copied `'use strict';` from angular-seed and now i'm understanding what it is doing. You solved my problem. Now, my code still has an error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. but when I `console.log(prefs)`, the array is returned. any idea ?

Comment: Yes, you need to write more defensive code.  Basically wrap `if (prefs) {}` around your `for (j = 0...` loop.  It's because of a race condition... you're using ngResource and referencing `$scope.users` in your filter before it has loaded.

Comment: ok. i corrected all the typos, and the mistakes you pointed. Thanks a lot. It's working when the page loads (plunker updated). How can i make it change each time I click a checkbox, or when i click a button ?