# Search OR filter element list created with ngrepeat

Tags: search, angularjs, filter

With your help, i made a [filter list with multiple checkboxes in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275926/filter-list-with-multiple-checkboxes-in-angularjs) .

Then, I added a search box. here is the code with the search field and the checkboxes working well together: http://plnkr.co/edit/eFaVuyXcUA07oeGwTYvC?p=preview

Now, i would like that as soon as the user starts to type in, the results would not be filtered by the checkboxes anymore (every available results would be visible, even those which should be hidden by the filters). It would be the checkbox filters results OR the search field results.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one that does what you want:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CZWSJFSXbTf6n5ey9L8C?p=preview

I'm just passing the query variable to your checkbox filter and disabling the filter if there is a query string.

Comment: It's not working anymore if i the search occurs on one column only. Do you know how i could make this work with `<input ng-model="query.reference">` ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were doing there.. I've updated the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PECt0lzA2gBuU1btGRMC?p=preview

Comment: thank you. that's working fine in the plunker. when i replicated this in my app, the result table is blank when i am first loading the page, and it's starting to work well only after the first search. any idea where this could come from ?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your code.  Maybe it has something to do with the way you're loading your data?  I assume your real code is doing an ajax call...