# Checkbox filter with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Do I need to create a custom filter in AngularJS to filter the elements in a ng-repeat by object property?

For instance, my JSON gives as a response:

```
artist: "Limp Bizkit"
id: 433390
main_release: 2518780
resource_url: "http://api.discogs.com/masters/433390"
role: "Main"
thumb: "http://api.discogs.com/image/R-150-2518780-1288430478.jpeg"
title: "Counterfeit"
type: "master"
year: 1997
```

I want to have a checkbox that will filter by "role", so I thought about something like the ng-model of every checkbox defining as true or false statements like this:

filter:{ role: \'main\' }
filter:{ role: \'remix\' }
filter:{ role: \'trackappeared\' }

Am I thinking in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Definetly creating a custom filter should be the way to go.

Here's an answer to a similar question (possible duplicate):

[Filtering by multiple checkboxes in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457809/filtering-by-multiple-checkboxes-in-angularjs)