# Error Reading from JSON File from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to read a simple file from my PODController in AngularJS:

```
  <script>
      function PODController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('POD.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.results = data.results;
          console.log("Here");
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('error');
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Just like: [Filtering by multiple checkboxes in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457809/filtering-by-multiple-checkboxes-in-angularjs)
and his example on plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/lNJNYagMC2rszbSOF95k?p=preview

But it seems like I am getting a:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/simon_zhu/Desktop/initializr/POD.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Both files are in the same folder and he seems to be doing it fine in his example. Is there something I missed?

Comment: You need to host your json file on a web server.

Comment: yea. i missed that it seems. thanks.

Comment: @Donal - or `localserver`.

Comment: not hard to set up a localhost server on your own machine and not hard to find numerous packages for it in web search