# Search multiple data in same column in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-filters

I try to write a code which search multiple data in same column using checkbox in Angularjs filter

[image]

As you can see in the picture the column office has ability to search multiple data at once.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Stack overflow itself gives you related questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457809/filtering-by-multiple-checkboxes-in-angularjs?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Go through this, there are all demos available, one of them is exact same as you want : http://iamisti.github.io/mdDataTable/

From this try ajax column filter support(new).